# Is there an elegant way using TypeORM to find one record in an array of OneToMany relation and assign it to another field in the entitiy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm looking for a way to implement a function, using NestJS and TypeORM, that will find in OneToMany array a specific element and assign that value to another field in the object.
And most important: implemented in a single place in the code.

For example:

The Entity `profile` have an array of `photos`, one of the photos is the profile picture. 
I would like to find that photo in the array and assign it to `profilePicture` if exist, on every select query.
is there a way in typeORM to implement that in a single place in the code?

```
@Entity('profile')
export class Profile extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @OneToMany(type => Photo, photo => photo.profile)
    photos?: Photo[];

    profilePicture?: Photo;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the query builder, you can achieve that by using leftJoinAndMapOne. I just wanted to add an example, but I just found out that the [TypeORM docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#joining-and-mapping-functionality) already have a good solution for your use case:

```
 const user = await createQueryBuilder("user")
.leftJoinAndMapOne("user.profilePhoto", "user.photos", "photo", "photo.isForProfile = TRUE")
.where("user.name = :name", { name: "Timber" })
.getOne();
```

Edit: Alternatively you can set the profile in your entity using the Afterload decorator:

```
@AfterLoad()
private setProfile(): void {
    this.photos.forEach((photo) => {
        if (photo.isForProfile) {
            this.photo = value;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I edited the question, I'm looking for a solution to implement in a single place in the code. So that the assignment will happen on automatically on every select query like TypeORM's `transformer`. I'll use leftJoinAndMapOne if there's no solution as I am looking for.