# One-to-one and one-to-many with same entity

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I have two entities user and address. So user can have multiple address (oneTomany) and also each user also have primaryAddress(one-to-one) relationship with address entity. How can I design this both entities?

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToMany((type) => Address, (address) => address.user)
    addresses: Address[];

    @OneToOne((type) => Address)
    primaryAddress: Address;

}



import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Address {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    addr1: string;

    @Column()
    addr2: string;

    @Column()
    city: string;

    @Column()
    state: string;

    @Column()
    zip: string;

    @Column()
    isPrimaryAddress: boolean;

    @ManyToOne((type) => User, (user) => user.addresses)
    user: User;
}
```

Comment: Please, add some of your code and maybe some example of what you tried.

Comment: added the code which was i tried,

Comment: I have similar problem, but I thought about different implementation.
Maybe it will help you somehow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61407959/is-there-an-elegant-way-using-typeorm-to-find-one-record-in-an-array-of-onetoman

Comment: Did you ever find a decent solution for this?